# Printing contents of list with indices from other list

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

I have two lists: L stores some values and P holds values that are indices in the first list that should be printed. Lists are sorted in ascending order. Error-checking can be ignored, and both lists are valid and values are valid.

Do I understand correctly, that since I always continue from the place I ended at, and since the values in both lists only increase, the cost of this operation is \$O(n)\$, since I only iterate over the list once?

I'd like to clean up the code. For example, is there a way to get the current index from the iterator, that would remove two additional `int` variables?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using std::list;

void printLots(const list<int> &l, const list<int> &p);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    list<int> listL;
    listL.push_back(2);
    listL.push_back(4);
    listL.push_back(6);
    listL.push_back(8);
    listL.push_back(10);
    listL.push_back(12);
    listL.push_back(14);
    listL.push_back(16);
    listL.push_back(18);
    listL.push_back(20);

    list<int> listP;
    listP.push_back(0);
    listP.push_back(9);

    printLots(listL, listP);
}

void printLots(const list<int> &l, const list<int> &p) {

    auto lIterator = l.begin();
    auto pIterator = p.begin();

    int lIndex = 0;
    int pIndex = 0;

    bool finished = false;

    while (!finished) {
        int indexToPrint = *pIterator;

        while (lIndex != indexToPrint) {
            lIndex++;
            lIterator++;
        }

        std::cout << *lIterator << std::endl;
        pIndex++;
        pIterator++;

        if (pIterator == p.end()) {
            finished = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few simplifications you can make:

**Unused variables**

The value of `pIndex` isn't used anywhere, so you can just get rid of it it.

**Simplifying outer loop**:

1. There is no need for `finish`, just put the (inverted) check into the loop condition (this will then also enable you to process empty lists).
2. You can write your outer loop as a simpler (semantically equivalent) for loop:

   ```
   for (auto pIterator = p.begin(); pIterator != p.end(); ++pIterator) {
       int indexToPrint = *pIterator;

       while (lIndex != indexToPrint) {
           lIndex++;
           lIterator++;
       }
       std::cout << *lIterator << std::endl;       
   }
   ```

**Using STL algorithms**

If you want to advance an iterator by a certain number, you can use std::advance instead of a loop:

```
std::advance(lIterator, indexToPrint - lIndex);
lIndex = indexToPrint;
```

**Alternative Implementation (using range based for loop)**

```
void printLots(const list<int> &l, const list<int> &p) {
    auto it = l.begin();
    int itIdx = 0;
    for (auto idx : p) {
        std::advance(it, idx - itIdx);
        itIdx = idx;
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    }   
}
```

A final remark: although, you said error checking is not necessary, I'd probably at least put an assert into place, that checks that the indices in p don't exceed the size of the list you want to print elements from.

Answer (score 3):

- It doesn't look like you're using `<stdio.h>`, so you can just remove it.
- If you won't ever need to provide command line arguments, then you can remove `main()`'s parameters.
- If you'll *just* be iterating though these lists forward, then it may be more beneficial to use an `std::forward_list` instead.  Or maybe you can just use an `std::vector` if there's no special need for a linked list.
- Your list assignments is still pre-C++11.  Instead, use its initializer list:

  ```
  list<int> listL { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20 };

  list<int> listP { 0, 9 };
  ```

  This will also allow you to make them `const` right away.